# How can I multiply two variables inside the string in dart?

Tags: string, dart, string-interpolation

`"${element['price'] * element['step']} c"`

always showing error

```
The operator '*' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
```

The result must be multiplied two variables and convert to string.

What is wrong? I can not find any answer. Making as documentation says.

The `element` is

```
var element = {
  'title': 'Apple and more more thing',
  'category': 'Fruit',
  'description': 'Some data to describe',
  'price': 24.67,
  'bonus': '1% bonus',
  'group': 'Picnik',
  'step': 1.0
};
```

Comment: What type is `element`?

Comment: The piece of code your are showing should work, the variables inside the element don't seem to be of a type that Dart recognises as being able to use the multiplies operator with. I would suggest verifying the output of those two variables.

Comment: as @julemand101 said type is not understandable try with parse - "${element['price'].toInt() * element['step'].toInt()} c"

Comment: @NileshSenta If the type from the map are seen as `Object` it will not work with `toInt()` since you cannot call `toInt()` on `Object`.

Comment: So you have a `Map` which contains multiple types of objects as values? Well, that is the reason why Dart have automatically declared the map as `Map<String, Object>` which means you need to type cast objects taken from this map. I will suggest creating a class with your data instead so you can get type safety.

Comment: @julemand101 there is a repeated `key` `group`

Comment: @dev-aentgs The example was not provided when I write my comment. But yes, the repeated group are also problematic here...

Comment: key - group edited. The error still appears.

Comment: It is used in Flutter Text widget, maybe there is some reason on it?

Comment: This has nothing to do with "[multiplying] inside [a] string".  You'd get the same error if you had done: `var result = element['price'] * element['step'];`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dart is a static type safe language so before your code are even running, the code has been analyzed to be sure that there are no statically determined type issues.

In your example your have defined the following variable:

```
var element = {
  'title': 'Apple and more more thing',
  'category': 'Fruit',
  'description': 'Some data to describe',
  'price': 24.67,
  'bonus': '1% bonus',
  'group': 'Picnik',
  'step': 1.0
};
```

By using `var` your are telling Dart that it should automatically determine the type. This can also be done in this case. Dart will see that all the keys in the map are `String` so we can safely assume the key type to be `String`.

Then it looks at the values and tries to find a type which are common for all values. Since we have both `double` and `String` as values the type must be `Object` since we cannot be more specific if we want a type which contain all values.

So the type of the map will be determined to be: `Map<String, Object>`.

When you are then using the `[]` operator on the map it will be defined to return `Object` from this map since this is the only thing we can be sure of.

But this is a problem when you try to do:

```
"${element['price'] * element['step']} c"
```

Since we in the analyzer phase can see we are going to call the `*` operator on `Object` the analyzer will then stop your program with a type error since what your are trying to do is not seen as type safe.

There are multiple ways to fix it which you can also see in other answers:

### Type cast

You can tell Dart "hey, I know what I am doing" and force Dart to use a specific type with:

```
"${(element['price'] as double) * (element['step'] as double)} c"
```

### Dynamic

You can declare your map to contain `dynamic` as value:

```
var element = <String, dynamic>{
  'title': 'Apple and more more thing',
  'category': 'Fruit',
  'description': 'Some data to describe',
  'price': 24.67,
  'bonus': '1% bonus',
  'group': 'Picnik',
  'step': 1.0
};
```

This will remove all type safety of values in the map and you can then do anything you want with the values coming from the map without worrying about type issues by the analyzer. But the types will then be checked on runtime which can make your application crash if you gets the type wrong (like the type cast).

### Class solution

You should really not use `Map` like you are doing. Instead, create a class:

```
void main() {
  var element = Element(
      title: 'Apple and more more thing',
      category: 'Fruit',
      description: 'Some data to describe',
      price: 24.67,
      bonus: '1% bonus',
      group: 'Picnik',
      step: 1.0);

  print("${element.price * element.step} c"); // 24.67 c
}

class Element {
  String title;
  String category;
  String description;
  double price;
  String bonus;
  String group;
  double step;

  Element(
      {this.title,
      this.category,
      this.description,
      this.price,
      this.bonus,
      this.group,
      this.step});
}
```

By doing so, you can ensure Dart know the type of each property and get type safety.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to cast them to a specific type. For example if they are of type `double`:

`"${(element['price'] as double) * (element['step'] as int)} c"`

Edited after you added your object to your question. changed 'step' to an int.

Comment: type 'int' is not a  subtype of type 'double' in type cast.

Comment: This means that either one or both of the `element[...]` is of type `int`. So instead of `as double` you should try `as int`

Comment: @NurbekBatyrzhanuulu `"${(element['price'] as double) * (element['step'] as int)} c"`

Comment: Nothing changed : (

Comment: @NurbekBatyrzhanuulu What if you assign the elements to variables first? `double price = element['price'] as double;` `int step = element['step'] as int;` and then convert them to a string `String s = "${price * step} c"`

Comment: If you are unsure if the value is either an `int` or `double` just use `num` as type